# Toggles between red and green graphic images

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick

I want an image that goes from green graphic to red graphic or red graphic to green graphic every time I click it. What do I need to do?

Comment: Hmm, maybe click?

Comment: @ScaryWombat hahaha, sorry but I did enjoy your comment. 
for the question -> please try animation where you can update the gradient or just use something like https://lottiefiles.com/animation/graphics

Comment: I think you should use the checkbox here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the tint of ImageView as follow.

```
fun setImageTint(view: ImageView, color: Int) {
    view.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(view.context, color), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
}
```

Then you can toggle your imageview as follow for example.

```
setImageTint(yourImageView, toggle ? R.color.red : R.color.green)
```